# React Hook "useSlideScroll" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I implemented a hook who is call useSlideScroll, and I called him inside a onClick button. There is a problem when I build my app, the problem is :

```
Error: React Hook "useSlideScroll" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I've created a dir hook where I put useSlideScroll hook. This is the code :

```
export const useSlideScroll = (element, speed, distance, step) => {
  let scrollAmount = 0
  const slideTimer = setInterval(() => {
    element.scrollLeft += step
    scrollAmount += Math.abs(step)
    if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
      clearInterval(slideTimer)
    }
  }, speed)
}
```

And I called him inside this component:

```
<Image
  src={'/images/prevArrow.svg'}
  alt="arrow down"
  height="10"
  width="10"
  className="cursor-pointer h-[10px] width-[10px]"
  onClick={() => useSlideScroll(scrollRef.current, 25, 100, -10)}
  />
```

What's the problem ? Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: You're breaking the [rules of hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). Also, based on your mutable variables and direct DOM manipulation you've misunderstood the architecture of React, I suggest reading ["Thinking in React"](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react)

Comment: I didn't undestand , but thank you for your time

Comment: `useSlideScroll` is not actually a custom react hook, if you change that function's name, you'll not get the error.

Comment: Thank you Titus. But why this solution ? I didn't undestard

Comment: In React, functions that start with `use..` are considered custom hooks, and those as well as the builtin hooks have to be directly inside components, not nested inside another function. In this case, `useSlideScroll` is not a custom hook (it doesn't use stuff like `useState` or `useEffect` inside of it) so it can be nested inside a function. My explanation is not that good, you should go through the documentation references Undo provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render cycle of a React component relies on the constant order of hooks invocation. If you call hook in callback the order will be changed.

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

You probably should return callback function from your hook and call it later.

```
const useSlideScroll = () = {
  const scroll = () ={//…}
  return scroll
}
```